# search user input from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I require some help with my homework.

I am currently trying to create a dictionary to store word as a key and sentence as a value into a text file. I am having issue trying to display the word if the word is already in the text file.

```
file = open('abc.txt','a+')

word_searching = str(input("word search??? "))
sentence = str(input("sentence?? "))

dictionary[word_searching] = sentence

for key, val in dictionary.items():
    file.write(str(key) + ':'+ str(val) + '\n')

file.close()

f = open('abc.txt','r+')
allLines = f.readlines()

for word in allLines:
    if word == 'word1':
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')

f.close()
```

I see that my allLines is a list with `['word1:sentence1\n','word2:sentence2\n']`. Even though `'word1'` is inside the text file, it does not display 'yes'.

UPDATE:
Hi guys, I realized that my inputs are not stored in the dictionary, how may i resolve this issue?

Comment: "'word1' is inside the text file" is one thing, but you're checking if one of the lines of the file is exactly equal to 'word1'.

Comment: immediately I can see `f.close` which doesn't close the file because you don't call it; `f.close()`

Comment: @rognjosh how does that affects anything for this question?

Comment: @roganjosh I  have put the comment on edit while doing edit. So OP accepted after reading that it was obvious typo from OP side. I did ask about change in code.

Comment: @Poojan it's not an obvious typo and it stops items being flushed to file because it's totally valid code but doesn't call the function. That edit may or may not fundamentally change the program and you shouldn't just "correct" it

Comment: @roganjosh ok...

Comment: Did any of the solutions resolve your issue?

Comment: hi @Fletchy1995, I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve the sentence according to the word that i was searching for?

Comment: @Grappyzxc I'm sure there is, if you find the word it will return true.  Then if they are on the same line you could just print the line and you'll have the sentence.  Or I'm sure the dictionary has some sort of consistency to it, perhaps consider adding a deliminator at the end of the "sentence".  You could then print from the word to the deliminator, or print after the word to the deliminator.

Comment: Did the answers resolve your original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for word in allLines:
    if word == 'word1':
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

You are searching for an exact match of 'word1', instead of searching for a substring of 'word1' in a larger string.

That is what the == is doing in your code.

Instead, you want to do:

```
if 'word1' in word:
```

This will match substrings of 'word1' in word, instead of doing an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

your variable `word` is the whole line. e.g:

```py
word = 'word1:sentence1\n'
```

In order to get the key word you need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the sentence on `:`:

```py
for line in allLines:
    word, sentence = line.split(':')
    # now word = "word1" , sentence = "sentence1"
    if word == 'word1':
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this code:

```
return search in textToSearch
```

"search" would represent the word you are hunting for, and "textToSearch" would be the variable attached to your text file.  This should return a boolean variable (either True or False).  If it contains the text you are looking for it will return True, if it does not it will return False.

So you could modify your code to something like...

```
def searchWord(search,textToSearch):
    return search in textToSearch

if(searchWord(word , file)):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Hope this helps.